# intel ACM execution

Tags: intel, bios

Please, i have a doubt about intel ACM that i can't clarify... the texts i have read, included some intel manuals, seeems to me a bit ambiguous and not absolutely clear.

I would like to know whether is or not intel CSME who measures, loads and executes ACM module located at FIT before Reset Vector gets control, or else is the proper code pointed by Reset Vector who executes ACM module (so, after Reset Vector gets control). Even, may be the two alternatives are possible?

I apologize for my not very good english, and thanks so much for any response.